# how to use BeautifulSoup with lxml on Google App Engine with dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, beautifulsoup, lxml

I did necessary steps that I can run with success from shell:

```
pip install lxml -t lib
cd lib
python
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import lxml
>>> res = BeautifulSoup("<p>hello</p>","lxml")
>>> print res
<html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>
```

However on Google App Engine with `dev_appserver.py` with no success:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import lxml
 import lxml
 p1 = BeautifulSoup("<p>toto</p>","lxml")
```

the error is:

```
Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have lxml installed? `pip install lxml`

Comment: Yep, I updated question. It was one of my attempt installing python-lxml which does not exist at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lxml` library is a [built-in third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) for the Python 2.7 runtime, but it doesn't come with `dev_appserver.py` by default. You'll need to install it on your machine separately:

```
pip install lxml==2.3.5
```

See the "Using built-in bundled libraries with the local development server" section of [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).

When deploying, you'll need to add this to your `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3.5"
```

Comment: `pip show lxml` gives `Version: 4.2.5` why specifying a version?

Comment: App Engine only supports `2.3`, `2.3.5`, and `3.7.3`, see the link above.